# Why is the select() function not available in Flutter's cloud_firestore package?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

This question might be more targeted for the FlutterFirebase team.

When looking at the API documentation for the Firestore, we see that there is a function inside of the Query class called select() (See the documentation [here](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/Query.html#select)). However this function is not available in the cloud_firestore package. Is there any reasons why it has not been made available for the Flutter package?

I am guessing that we could work around and call the API directly instead of going through the package but that wouldn't be optimal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `select()` is a function in the Admin SDK, so on the server side. The `cloud_firestore` package is done to be used in the client side, it can be compared to [Javascript Firebase client SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8) which also doesn't have the `select()` function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That make sense and also I found this GitHub issue that explains the "why". https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/212

Comment: @Ak-dev Basically all those flutter plugins that you see on pub.dev or Github. They use methodchannel to call the APIs that are done in Android native(kotlin or Java) and in ios. If `select()` is not implemented there then for sure it won't be implemented in flutter.